# React Material UI Stepper always changes the icon to the "completed icon"

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, stepper

i am implementing material ui stepper to my project. what disturbs me , is that completed icon.

[image]

after moving to the next step, i want to keep number active icon. here is the link for linear mode

https://codesandbox.io/s/254fxz?file=/Demo.tsx

when i use the nonlinear mode, the first step becomes inactive which also does not suit my case.

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/kcpwdm?file=/Demo.tsx

does anybody has a workaround for my case ?

thanks in advance